# What should file paths fed to insertCSS() be relative to?

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, inappbrowser

I'm starting out with phonegap and have found the docs to be a bit vauge on this point.

When I use `insertCSS()` on [my current project](https://github.com/RedRiderX/chat-se-mobile-app) it seems like whatever path I use, the css is not used.

As you can see from that link, my file structure is:

```
app-root
|
...
|_ www
    |
    |_ css
    |   |
    |   target.css
    |
    |_ js
    |   |
    |   index.js
    |   
    index.html
```

In index.js I'm making a call to insertCSS() in the event listener for an inAppBrowser.

This function should be pulling target.css:

```
iab.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
    // Once loaded, add css
    iab.insertCSS( { file: "target.css" } );
});
```

But... it doesn't

I've tried multiple different relative file paths like `css/target.css` and `../css/target.css` but they don't seem to work.

What am I missing?

Comment: I posted a workaround on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098838/ -- which is a newer question but has more views, probably due to a more specific title.

Comment: I know this question is several years old. but if anyone has a solution please update.

Comment: @firefields Not sure if you situation is exactly the same as mine, but I ended up sort of avoided the issue here by inlining the css with js. As you said it's been a few years so I'm a bit fuzzy on the details, but you can see the code I used here: https://github.com/RedRiderX/chat-se-mobile-app/blob/master/www/js/index.js#L50

Comment: Thank you @RedRiderX that seems like a simple solution. I'll probably do the same

Answer (score 1):

Internal type styling in CSS generally have a higher order of precedence over external styling.

Therefore This (from your GitHub Code):

```
iab.insertCSS( { code: "body { background-color: green; }" }, function(){
  iab.insertCSS( { code: "body { background-color: green; }" } );
```

would always be executed instead of this:

```
iab.insertCSS( { file: "../css/chat.window.css" }
```

since they are both styling the same element. The complete order of precedence from top priority to least is:

1. Inline Style (top priority)
2. Internal Style
3. External Style (least priority)

Comment: Hmm that is a good point, I've removed what I believe you referred to as inline styling from my code. I did keep the external file call, but I can see that it still seems to have no effect. If external styles never have a chance to take effect on a page, why allow people to inject them? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @RedRiderX Is the code on GitHub the most current one? Because you only took out one of the Internal Styles. There's still one more before the file reference

Comment: I'm sorry, are you referencing [this section](https://github.com/RedRiderX/chat-se-mobile-app/blob/master/www/js/index.js#L45)? I believe that all the other references to inline styles have been removed.

Comment: @RedRiderX Ok. Great. But include the .CSS file in the JS directory (that contains index.js) and have your insert CSS this way: `iab.insertCSS({file: "chat.window.css"})`

Comment: Though I assume you meant `iab.insertCSS( { file: "chat.window.css" } );` after moving the files and changing the file path, the styles still seem to not apply. Is this related to the inheritance you mentioned before? Is there another way I should be going about this?

Comment: Maybe not directly related but I am using the online PhoneGap build tool, and those are the builds I'm testing with. https://build.phonegap.com/apps/871794/share